# How to debug Angular Provider issues

Tags: angular, systemjs, jspm

What is the best way to debug issues related to Angular providers that aren't resolving?

I have an Angular (NG2, not AngularJS) provider that doesn't resolve when a portion of my code is bundled using JSPM.

The only error message that Angular provides is:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataManager: (AppConfig, ?, DataStore)

The '?' parameter refers to a class "DataService".

Neither DataManager nor DataService are in the bundle.  Neither of them use classes that are in the bundle.  However, DataService depends on a class AppConfig which inherits from the bundle.

From the above message, Angular was able to resolve AppConfig, so I don't know if that's the problem.

- The bundle is being loaded onto the page before any of the classes mentioned above.
- If I don't use the bundle, the provider resolves successfully.
- We are using SystemJS instead of WebPack.
- We are using System.import to pre-load the classes above, prior to bootstrapping Angular.  (Reasons related to integration with legacy code.)
- If I don't pre-load this provider, it will eventually resolve fine even with the bundle.

Any tips would be appreciated for:

- How to troubleshoot Angular provider resolution
- How to make Angular be more verbose in errors
- How to ask this question better
- If I'm in the wrong forum, which forum would be more appropriate

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make a back up of your code, and start removing providers or adding providers one at a time to find the issue. Also make sure you are using the ng serve to test the build and not actually building the project. 
Check to see if you are using a stable version of your provider.
Is this originally your project? if not make sure you are using the correct version of node.js as the original build. (if your on mac use the NVM tool its great) also check if your are using the correct version of Java RTE on your machine, if you have other versions uninstall them and make sure your pointing to the right one. If you need help with that please look up as that has been answered before.

If your question is more complex then this please comment and I will update my answer. 
Please comment and follow up.

Comment: Thanks @James. Removing providers one at a time didn't provide any insight. It might be worth noting that the 'DataService' class does import properly via 'System.import' prior to 'DataManager' being instantiated. What I need might be a way to tell Angular "here's an instance of 'DataService' that you can use to satisfy its clients", or at least, a way to trace / step through how it tries to satisfy a DI reqt.

Comment: Hmm try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger
See if you can use a more advanced logging system to track your issue.